# Python's "with" statement doesn't create an object

Tags: python, with-statement

Here is the short piece of code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print '__init__'

    def __enter__(self):
        print '__enter__'

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print '__exit__'

    def print_message(self):
        print 'Works fine!'

with A() as a:
    a.print_message()
```

And when I run it I get the following:

```
__init__
__enter__
__exit__
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/.../IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    202             else:
    203                 filename = fname
--> 204             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/.../test.py in <module>()
     15 
     16 with A() as a:
---> 17     a.print_message()
     18 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print_message'
```

So, I wonder:

why the **exit** method is called before ending the with statement?

and why the "a" object is of NoneType?

Comment: You're only `print`ing in your functions, you're never actually `return`ing anything to be the context object

Comment: Thank you! I put "return self" to the __enter__ method, and it fixed my problem!